# How to use ArcGIS Online Web Maps/Apps to Collect Community Input securely?

Tags: arcgis-online, data-collection

I want to set up a computer at a public hearing that runs an ArcGIS Online Web Application from my subscription account where citizens can choose from predefined editable point layers I've already created (EX Critical Safety Issue, Transportation Need) to place points in our project study area. I've already customized the point features with the attributes I want to collect (Ex: Date, Name, Address, Comment etc) in a File Geodatabase in ArcCatalog.

My first thought was to use a Web Map which allows editing of layers. However, Web Maps are not very secure i.e. a citizen could alter another persons comment and so on. Looking for a direction to take to best implement a data collection web app that allows users to choose my predefined editable layers without being able to click on other citizen comments and edit those as well.

In short, I'm looking for a more secure editable Web App template. The big application would be to post this web app on a website to collect the input of people who can't make it to  public hearings. I apologize for the long winded question but does someone have a direction I can take? I may be overlooking some very obvious concepts of ArcGIS Online but I feel I should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something very similar by embedding a web app (where you can set editing options and include widgets) within a story journal. To stop users from deleting the comments of others, you can set the editing properties for the feature layer by selecting 'Edit' from its item details page.

[image]

Then set the editing properties to 'Add features only'.

[image]

You will need to make the application publicly accessible so that people outside of your organisation are able to view it, but could limit access by embedding the URL in a password protected web page or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ArcGIS Server you could utilize the [Public Information Center App](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8fad9c264f84425196bf95474aa3c7de) they have built.

I created a point and don't see any way for me to edit the other points that are on the [Try It Live](http://tryitlive.arcgis.com/PublicInfoCenter/) site.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question, I've run into very similar needs and have not yet found a great solution through arcgis online.

We currently implement the same goal (collecting public feedback as geocoded locations) using Shareabouts maps, a project of OpenPlans.

https://openplans.org/shareabouts/

They offer a range of map-based public feedback options, which you can see on their websites.  They have a business service where they'll help to set everything up for you, but they also opensource their software if you're interested in doing it yourself. You can get the data out of the Shareabouts and into ArcMap with minimal effort.

Hope that's useful!

~ Ben